# Is it possible to disable camera bumping?

Tags: diablo-iii

In diablo 3, certain spells cause the camera to shake a bit. For example, wizard's meteor or the barbarian's cleave. I want to know if it is possible to disable this.

The reason is that I have a build that use a lot one spell that cause the camera to shake, and so it disturbs me more than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an option to disable the screen shake caused by certain abilities and effects. There are however [a lot](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4210122703) [of requests](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4551589695) [to add](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5235401218?page=1) [an option](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5912123022?page=1) [to disable it](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5978349977).

[This one contains a blue post stating that the option currently doesn't exist](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5978349243?page=1).